# How to Generate SQL execution log in Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

Is there a way to get SQL Output(same as I am getting in SQL Plus/ Developer) while executing via Liquibase?
For Ex - The exact line in which an error occurred, Or How many rows executed

Comment: What do you mean with "while executing via liquibase"?